# How to match multiple texts in a String without using pattern matching in Java?

Tags: java, spring

I have the following string in Java:

```
"JAVA_SAMPLE _NEW=AT_YYUYU12_PROGRAM"
```

Is it possible using String.contains to match `"JAVA_SAMPLE" ^ "PROGRAM"`? I want to match two strings, but I don't want to use pattern matching.

Comment: `if (x.contains("JAVA") && x.contains("PROGRAM"))`?

Comment: If the substrings to match are at the beginning and end of your string as shown in your example `str.startsWith( "JAVA_SAMPLE") && str.endsWith("PROGRAM")`

Comment: Suggestions here are well and good, but the question itself isn't very clear. Using `starts/endsWith` is a start, but if the requirement is for `JAVA_SAMPLE` to simply be before `PROGRAM`, but not necessarily at the start/end, then you would need to get the index of the *first* substring, then start looking for the *second* one right after index+length of the first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Lambda expressions to achieve this

```
public boolean matches(String source, Collection<String> strings) {
    //Omitting source null check and empty collection logic here to keep it simple
    return strings.stream().allMatch(s -> source.contains(s));
}
```

This method has an argument that receives all strings you want to evaluate, here sample how to use it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "JAVA_SAMPLE _NEW=AT_YYUYU12_PROGRAM";
    Collection<String> strings = Arrays.asList("JAVA_SAMPLE", "PROGRAM");
    Matches m = new Matches();
    if(m.matches(x, strings)) {
        System.out.println("All good!");
    }
}
```